# Oracle project( true way of using foreign key and model )

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, oracle-sqldeveloper, primary-key

Hello so i make this but could not open model. i am getting this error. I know for model we need to use foreign and main keys but i am getting errors when i execute 1st code.  Is there any easy way to print models. plus i did not get this reference part i thought like that we are linking 2
foregn key .

```
ALTER TABLE Recipient
ADD FOREIGN KEY (firstName)
REFERENCES Donor(firstName);


CREATE TABLE Recipient( recipientID INT  NOT NULL,
firstName VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL, lastname VARCHAR( 50 ) not null,
address VARCHAR( 60 ) not null, email VARCHAR( 100 ) not null, 
phone VARCHAR( 20 ) not null,  birthday INT not null, bloodType varchar (3)NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (recipientID));

CREATE TABLE Donor( donorID INT  NOT NULL,firstName VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL, 
lastname VARCHAR(50) not null, address VARCHAR(60) not null, email VARCHAR( 100 ) not null, 
phone VARCHAR(20) not null, birthday INT not null, bloodtype VARCHAR(3)NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (donorID));


CREATE TABLE Blood_BANK( donorID INT NOT NULL , Blood_BANK VARCHAR(50) not null, Adress VARCHAR(50) not null,PRIMARY KEY(donorID));

Create TABLE Hospital(donorID INT NOT NULL, 
recipientID INT NOT NULL ,hospital VARCHAR(50),room INT NOT NULL,doctor VARCHAR(50) not null, primary key(hospital) );


CREATE TABLE doctor(  doctor VARCHAR(50) not null, hospital VARCHAR(50) not null, primary key (doctor));

CREATE SEQUENCE seq20
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;
INSERT INTO Donor (donorID,firstName, lastname, address, email,phone, birthday , bloodType)
VALUES (seq20.NEXTVAL,'Neriman','Nerimanov' , 'Marneuli'   ,'neriman@gmail.com' , 597156, 2004,'O+' ); 

CREATE SEQUENCE seq21
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 ;
INSERT INTO Recipient(recipientID, firstName,lastname,address,email,phone,birthday,bloodType)
VALUES ( seq21.NEXTVAL, 'Nizami', 'Lom', 'Batumi', 'lomnizami@gmail.com', 597931,2000,'O+');

drop sequence seq22;
CREATE SEQUENCE seq22
INCREMENT BY 1 START with 1;
INSERT INTO Blood_BANK (donorID, Blood_BANK , Adress) 
VALUES (seq22.NEXTVAL, 'Marneuli Hospital', 'Marneuli');

INSERT INTO doctor( doctor, hospital)
VALUES( 'Nana Oposhvili ', ' havit medical');

CREATE SEQUENCE seq23
INCREMENT BY 1 START with 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE seq24
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;

INSERT INTO Hospital(donorID,recipientID, hospital,room, doctor)
VALUES( seq23.NEXTVAL, seq24.NEXTVAL,'Havit medical',511,'Nana Oposhvili');
```

Error:

[image: error]

Model:

[image: model]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
[mre] PS What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified, this is what you did:

```
create table donor
  (donorID     int   primary key,
   firstname   varchar2(50),
   ...
  );
create table recipient
  (recipientID int   primary key,
   firstname   varchar2(50),
   ...
  );
alter table recipient add foreign key (firstname) references donor (firstname);
```

Error says that there's no matching primary or unique key in `DONOR` table which could then be referenced from the `RECIPIENT` table.

In other words: any table - which is supposed to reference the `DONOR` table - must reference its primary key column, and that is `donorID`. You can't reference `firstname`, it is *just a column* (nothing special about it) - you certainly won't make it a primary key, and having it as a unique key is even worse (there surely is more than just one Omar in the world (or in the `donor` table). If not now, it will be. First names are poor choice for unique keys.

Therefore, what to do? `recipient` table should have `donorid` column which would then reference `donor` table.

---

On the other hand: your data model seems to be wrong. There should be only one table that holds personal info (ID, first and last name, address, etc.). There should be another table which says which "roles" are possible (currently, a donor or a recipient). Finally, the third table which says which person acts which role.

Something like this (simplified, again):

```
SQL> create table person
  2    (person_id number constraint pk_pers primary key,
  3     first_name varchar2(20),
  4     last_name  varchar2(20),
  5     date_of_birth date
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> create table role
  2    (role_id number constraint pk_role primary key,
  3     name    varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create table person_x_role
  2    (person_id number constraint fk_pxr_pers references person (person_id),
  3     role_id   number constraint fk_pxr_role references role (role_id),
  4     --
  5     constraint pk_pxr primary key (person_id, role_id)
  6    );

Table created.
```

Inserts:

```
SQL> insert into person values (1, 'Little', 'Foot', date '2020-01-01');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into person values (2, 'Scott', 'Head', date '2010-02-03');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into role values (1, 'donor');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into role values (2, 'recipient');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into person_x_role values (1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into person_x_role values (2, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into person_x_role values (2, 2);

1 row created.
```

Tables' contents:

```
SQL> select * from person;

 PERSON_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME            DATE_OF_BI
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Little               Foot                 01.01.2020
         2 Scott                Head                 03.02.2010

SQL> select * From role;

   ROLE_ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 donor
         2 recipient

SQL> select * From person_x_role;

 PERSON_ID    ROLE_ID
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          1
         2          2
```

Query you might write:

```
SQL> select p.first_name, p.last_name, r.name role_name
  2  from person p join person_x_role x on x.person_id = p.person_id
  3                join role r on r.role_id = x.role_id;

FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME            ROLE_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Little               Foot                 donor
Scott                Head                 donor
Scott                Head                 recipient

SQL>
```

As you can see, Scott is both a donor and a recipient (why not? There's such a chance).

Comment: Perhaps an addition: add date column to `person_x_role` table, of course adjust the PK. This permits the same person to have the same role on multiple occasions and and BTY when.